# show that $ \sum \frac{1}{n}e^{-n^2 t}\sin{(nx)}$ converges in $L^2([0,\pi])$ to $ \sum \frac{1}{n}\sin{(nx)}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, trigonometry, uniform-convergence

I would like to show that

$$ \sum_{\substack{n=1 \\ n \text{ odd}}}^\infty \frac{1}{n}e^{-n^2 t}\sin{(nx)}$$

converges in $L^2([0,\pi])$ to

$$ \sum_{\substack{n=1 \\ n \text{ odd}}}^\infty \frac{1}{n}\sin{(nx)}$$

as $t\to 0$.

Now I have

\begin{align} &\lim_{t\to 0} \int_0^\pi \left| \sum_{\substack{n=1 \\ n \text{ odd}}}^\infty \frac{1}{n}e^{-n^2 t}\sin{(nx)} -  \sum_{\substack{n=1 \\ n \text{ odd}}}^\infty \frac{1}{n}\sin{(nx)} \right|^2\\
= &\lim_{t\to 0} \int_0^\pi \left| \sum_{\substack{n=1 \\ n \text{ odd}}}^\infty \frac{1}{n}\sin{(nx)} (e^{-n^2 t} - 1) \right|^2.
\end{align}

I am comfortable moving the $\lim_{t\to 0}$ under the sum, since certainly the sum converges uniformly for $t$ near 0. But what would justify my moving it under the integral?

Comment: I don't really know any formal analysis so this is probably off topic, but the first series looks like it can be evaluated in terms of the integral of a theta function, while the second one could be evaluated explicitly in terms of elementary functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Parseval, the problem reduces to showing
$$\lim_{t\to 0}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(1-e^{-n^2t})^2}{n^2}=0$$
which is not hard: the series is dominated by $1/n^2$, so it converges uniformly in $t$.